# How to remove language part of $uri for purpose of try_files in nginx 1.6?

Tags: nginx, regex

I have a site with language prefixes in $uri, for example:

- http://www.example.com/en/some/content
- http://www.example.com/ru/novost

Sadly, due to limitations of framework I'm using, files are also linked / looked for under prefixed addresses:

- http://www.example.com/files/image.png (this is valid and expected)
- http://www.example.com/en/files/image.png
- http://www.example.com/ru/files/image.png

What I want my nginx to do is to try files in following order:

1. `$uri` as is
2. `/files/image.png` (even if en or ru or any other two-letter code was present)
3. `/index.php` to get file generated if applicable

1. and 3. can be (are) done with simple:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}
```

I know about ~* command to tell Nginx to do a regex match ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16726219/2389310)). Sadly, I have no idea how to formulate match to *omit* potential group instead of selecting it. And trying with variables before and after made me try to use `if` - of course I want to avoid that.

I believe I'm missing something relatively simple.

Comment: Simply, don't capture the group. What location regex did you try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the language part is a two lowercase characters string, this is possible to achieve this with :

```
location ~ "^(?:/[a-z]{2})?/(.*)$" {
    try_files /$1 /index.php;
}
```

Comment: You mean, as second location, defined before the / one? So simple, thank you, will try asap.

Comment: As the first capture group is not mandatory, you don't need another location.

Comment: Thank you, with that last comment I finally think I get it :)